# Using QGIS batch-processing dissolve?

Tags: qgis, dissolve, batch

How to use QGIS batch-processing dissolve:

[image]

Using QGIS 2.16 under Win 10 (see screenshot). Questions:

1. Why must I have at least two rows. When I open the window I have 3 rows. Using the red minus-icon, I can delete one row, but not two rows. I think I only need one row, because I want to dissolve only one file (layer).
2. The last right-most cell of each row is for the output of the dissolve-process, right? Should I simple enter a filename like output.shp here?
3. Anybody got this working under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Batch processing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html) allows you to run the same tool on **more than one file/layer**, hence the minimum rows of two. If you only need to run the tool on **one layer**, just run the tool normally by double left-click (or `right-click > Execute`).
2. The last right-most cell for each show should be the `Load in QGIS` parameter, which asks you if you want the output to be immediately loaded into QGIS. You should define a path either manually or click the ellipses button.
3. I don't use Windows 10 ([don't want to make it easier for people to track what I'm doing](http://www.theverge.com/2016/8/22/12582622/eff-microsoft-windows-10-privacy-concerns)) but it works perfectly fine on Windows 7.